# How can I remove the single quotes from a string and use it for division in Python?

Tags: python

How can I remove `'` from the string `'/'` and use it for division in Python?

For example:

```
a='/'
b=6
c=3

bac
```

The answer should be 2.

Comment: the original is one string? "`a='/' b=6 c=3" ?  And you want to break that up and do a calculation with it?

Comment: Are you trying to write a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser)? Or something else? It's hard to see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: no its 3 separate variables i'm talking about the '/' specifically

Comment: `eval('{}{}{}'.format(b, a, c))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has an [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) function that can do this:

```
a = "/"
b = "6"
c = "3"
print eval(b + a + c)
```

However, please note that if you're getting input from a remote source (like over a network), then passing such code to `eval()` is potentially very dangerous. It would allow network users to execute arbitrary code on your server.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the built-in operators as functions from the `operator` module:

```
import operator

a = operator.div
b = 6
c = 3

print a(b, c)
```

If you want to get the correct operator by the symbol, build a dict out of them:

```
ops = {
    "/": operator.div,
    "*": operator.mul,
    # et cetera
}

a = ops["/"]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no single quotes in the variable `a`. Python just uses these to denote `a` represents a `string`. `b` and `c` represent `int`s and don't have the single quotes. If you ensure all of these variables are strings, you can [**`join()`**](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them together:

```
>>> a='/'
>>> b=6
>>> c=3
>>> bac = ''.join(str(x) for x in (b, a, c))
>>> bac
'6/3'
```

See how there are single quotes at the beginning and end of the string.

You could then use [**`eval()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) (with caution) to perform the division:

```
>>> eval(bac)
2
```

**Related**: [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)